# Не срабатывает переход после авторизации Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

После введения логина и пароля, указанного в websecurityconfig сервлет должен с index.jsp перебрасывать на admin.jsp, но показывает ошибку 404. В отладке я не дохожу до метода, который обрабатывает запрос /admin. В чем может быть ошибка?

сервлет

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {

    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView admin() {

    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("admin");
    return model;
}
```

AppConfig

```
  @Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
            = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    //viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

index.jsp

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to Javatpoint! <br> <br>
<a href="admin">Admin login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin").password("admin123").roles("ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/index", "/user","/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin() // It renders a login form
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: `сервлет должен с index.jsp перебрасывать на admin.jsp`.. почему?.. где это написано?

Comment: в index.jsp ссылка на admin

Comment: `в index.jsp ссылка на admin` и это никак  не заставит спринг сделать редирект...это просто верстка

Comment: А что мне нужно исправить, чтобы оно обрабатывалось методом сервлета с value=/admin?

Comment: чтобы был автоматический редирект или чтобы обрабатывался?

Comment: для редиректа после авторизации после `formLogin()` вызовите `defaultSuccessUrl("/admin", true)`

Comment: чтобы был редирект на страницу admin, но так как к ней доступ только авторизованным пользователем доступен, сначала была страница login(ну это у меня сделано)

Comment: см ответ. если что не получится - напишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin").password("admin123").roles("ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/index", "/user","/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin() // It renders a login form
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin", true) // <---------------
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }
}
```